# Deleting a component linked to many items

Tags: tridion

I have a component that is linked to many thousands of items (in this case all the other items are components). Is there an easy/fast way to delete the component and remove all the links?

I am currently using Tridion 5.3 and and doing this programmatically via the TOM API. For one component that was linked to 10000 other components this took about 7 hours. I have many more to go!

I am in the process of migrating from R5.3 to 2011 so can use either for the task.

The code I am using is as follows...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var componentIDToRemove = "tcm:4-123456";

    var linkedComponentIDs = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\\...\\whereused.txt"); // ids of the components linked to tcm:4-123456

    TDS.TDSE tdse = new TDS.TDSE();

    foreach (var linkedComponentID in linkedComponentIDs)
    {
        TDS.Component component = null;
        TDS.ItemFieldValues itemFieldValues = null;

        try
        {
            component = (TDS.Component)tdse.GetObject(linkedComponentID, TDSDefines.EnumOpenMode.OpenModeView);

            itemFieldValues = component.MetadataFields["myfield"].value;

            var itemFieldValuesCount = itemFieldValues.Count;
            for (var i = itemFieldValuesCount; i > 0; i--)
            {
                if (itemFieldValues[i].ID == componentIDToRemove)
                {
                    component.CheckOut();
                    itemFieldValues.Remove(i);
                    component.Save();
                    component.CheckIn();
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // release the TDS objects from memory
            ReleaseObject(component);
            ReleaseObject(itemFieldValues);
        }
    }
}

public static void ReleaseObject(object o)
{
    try
    {
        if (o != null)
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(o);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have doubt about your code, share it so we can have a look at it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen my question wasn't so much about how to speed up code (which I've added just in case I'm doing something crazy). I was asking more about if there was any other solution rather than using the TOM API. Running a script on the DB would be the fastest way but also could be quite dangerous. I was hoping there was a script/program I was unaware of.

Comment: Code looks good.  Maybe the DBA can monitor resources while the script is running?  Running a script on the DB would be faster, but could have some unintended side-effects that would be difficult to recover from.

Comment: Are the links _in_ that component or _from_ other components? And do you know which field to specifically check (i.e. do you need the loop?).

Comment: Is it possible that your component could be linked multiple times in the metadata? If so, you will be checking-out, saving and checking-in repeatedly. Probably not the case but it may speed things  up a little. It is typically the ".Save()" that takes the time for such scripts. Also consider using .Save(true) instead of checking-in each time.

Comment: @AlvinReyes I have changed the code example a little because I think it was a little confusing. I am looping through the values of a particular multivalued field. The linked component could be in any position so I have to check every item

Comment: @ChrisSummers That's one thing I didn't mention, the component is only linked once so the checkout will happen just once. I have tried `Save(true)` in the past but found no noticeable performance increase.

Comment: I'm just curious; why on earth did you have such incredible amounts of links in the first place? I suspect you'll find removing them helps a lot.

Comment: @DominicCronin Taxonomy purposes. The meta data for every component has a number of component link fields that allow the component to be associated with zero or more "taxonomy components". So a component may have a field called "TargetAudience" which could link to "Employee", "Manager", "Anyone" etc. This information feeds into the Autonomy search when a component is published. It's crazy.

Comment: Makes sense if the "TargetAudience" components could be re-used or "templates," otherwise embeddable schemas and keywords might have been _less crazy_. No script I know of, but you might get a small performance gain if you know where this component normally exists and/or the authors had a convention when linking. For example, you might want to loop from 0 _up_ to `itemFieldValuesCount` if the linked item is typically "higher" in the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a script via TOM is the best way to do it.  The Core Service API in Tridion 2011 is probably not much faster.

From my experience the following are best practice when using TOM via Interop in .NET.

- Explicitly declare all objects and release them.  For example:

  ```
  // do this
  var items = folder.GetItems(16);
  foreach(var item in items)
  {
      // ...
  }
  if(items != null)
  {
      Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(items);
  }

  // instead of this
  foreach(var item in folder.GetItems(16))
  {
      // ...
  }
  ```
- If passing an object to a method - pass the URI instead of the object and declare a new instance of the object within the method and explicitly release it inside the method.
- Declare a single instance of TDSE and reference it. Creating multiple instances is a more expensive option.
- Where Used can take a long time and is heavy on the database. Update database indexes and run maintenance scripts before running the code.

Comment: Thanks @robrtc. I have posted my code in my question. I think I'm doing everything right? Like I said to Frank, I was hoping there was a script/program I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be triggering two garbage collections each time you process a component. This is almost certainly going to affect your performance quite a lot.

As for the TOM - most of the important things have been said by others, although I don't think anyone has mentioned that ItemField collections are *incredibly* slow when compared to using the XML API to do the same job. In other words, load an XmlDocument (or perhaps XDocument) using GetXml()... manipulate the XML directly, push it back in with UpdateXml() and Save.

Comment: Would you recommend garbage collecting just the once on the `component`? (maybe the `itemFieldValues` gets collected with the component?). Or where else would you put the garbage collection? I haven't run a profiler over my code but just stepping through, the garbage collection completes instantaneously while there is a noticeable lag in the calling the TOM API.

Comment: Don't force the garbage collection at all. Let the garbage collector decide. In the time frames associated with stepping in the debugger, you won't notice the GC.

Comment: Ok. So there's no need to call `GC.Collect();` and `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();`?

Comment: Exactly. Those methods are exposed by GC for people writing specialist tooling and the like. You shouldn't need to call them in normal code.